# CSS animation based on scroll position

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I am trying to animate a `div` depending on the users’ scroll position. For that I am using a JavaScript event listener which sets a dynamic CSS variable as `body` property which delivers a value between 0 (top of page) and 1 (bottom of page):

JavaScript:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  document.body.style.setProperty('--scroll',window.pageYOffset / (document.body.offsetHeight - window.innerHeight));
}, false);
```

In CSS, I use animation-delay to make use of that variable:

```
animation-delay: calc(var(--scroll) * -1s);
```

However, I would only like to use the animation in the header, and not throughout the whole page. How can I limit the `--scroll` variable to be limited only to a specific section of the page?

Here’s a Codepen of my animation which currently spans across the whole body height: https://codepen.io/grflu/pen/BazByyj

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried setting the  --scroll variable just to the header ?

Comment: Yes, the values remain the same.